# Configuration of the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) reporting with `report-to` in the HTML `meta`-tag

Tags: content-security-policy

I've defined a content security policy (CSP) for my SPA-application via the `meta`-tag:

```html
<meta content = "default-src https: 'self' https://%SOME_DOMAIN%.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none';"
      http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" />
```

Everything is working, and in case of a violation I see a warning in the console.
Now, I want to send an automatic report to the back-end with the `report-to` directive.

Do I understand it correctly that due to security reasons I can configure the `report-to` only on the backend and send it to the client-side only as a HTTP-header, and I can't just declare it in the `meta`-tag, just like I've done with the content-security-policy rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you understand it correctly. [Reporting API](https://www.w3.org/TR/reporting/) works only via HTTP header.
Moreover `report-to`/`report-uri` CSP directives are not supported in `meta`-tag.

If you wish to get violation reports, CSP should be delivered from the server as HTTP header.
In case of use `report-uri` directive you do not need anything special, but in case of use `report-to` directive, you additionally need to publish a special `Report-to` HTTP header from the server.

PS: Only Chrome supports `Reporting API`/`report-to` directive as for now.